# GPS receiver + Ublox NEO-6M - Having trouble making a timeout

Tags: arduino, gps, nodemcu

I'm trying to write some code that will turn on the gps module and wait for data to arrive, so that I can then do things with it. I don't need a continuous stream; I only need the first lat/long  received from the gps unit, then I can turn it off. I also need this to just stop if it can't find it's location within a certain amount of time (20 seconds for example)

Here is some simple code that I've tried just to get the gps to read (full code with timeout comes later)

```
    #include <TinyGPS++.h>

    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
    TinyGPSPlus gps;  // The TinyGPS++ object
    SoftwareSerial ss(D4, D3); // The serial connection to the GPS     
    float latitude , longitude;
    int count = 0;


    void setup()
    {

      Serial.begin(9600);
      ss.begin(9600);
      Serial.println();
      Serial.print("Starting");

    }

    void loop()
    {
      while (ss.available() > 0)
        if (gps.encode(ss.read()))
        {
          if (gps.location.isValid())
          {
            latitude = gps.location.lat();
            lat_str = String(latitude , 6);
            longitude = gps.location.lng();
            lng_str = String(longitude , 6);
          }

        }
      Serial.println(lat_str + ":" + lng_str);
      delay(100);
      count += 1;
      String Count = String(count);
      Serial.println(Count);
    }
```

When the delay above is 100, then everything works fine, when the delay is 1000, then suddenly no data comes through.

Here is the full code I've tried that includes my timeout and breakout condition, again not working. The cutoff line is in the GPS_mode function here:  while ((stoploop < 1) && (previous - startTime < TimeOut)).

```
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
    #include <TinyGPS++.h>
    TinyGPSPlus gps;  // The TinyGPS++ object
    SoftwareSerial ss(D4, D3); // The serial connection to the GPS d

    int stoploop = 0; //used for stopping gps once a signal lock or     timeout is reached
    unsigned long startTime = millis(); // timer used for gps timeout
    const int gpsCutoffPin = D1;

    void setup() {
      //initialise the serial monitor
      Serial.begin(9600);
      gps_ss.begin(9600);
      //initialise the transistor pins
      pinMode(gpsCutoffPin, OUTPUT);
      // Start the gps in an off state
      digitalWrite(gpsCutoffPin, LOW);
    }

    void loop() {
        Serial.println("Enter GPS mode");
        GPS_mode();
        Serial.println("Back to the main loop now...");
        Serial.println(stoploop);
        delay(100000);
    }

    void GPS_mode(){
      //turn on the gps
      digitalWrite(gpsCutoffPin, HIGH);
      stoploop = 0;
      startTime = millis();
      previous = millis();
      int TimeOut = 60*1000;
      gps_ss.listen();
      Serial.println(stoploop);
        while ((stoploop < 1) && (previous - startTime < TimeOut))
      {
        while (gps_ss.available() > 0)
        {
          if (gps.encode(gps_ss.read()))
          {
            logInfo();
          }
          yield();
        }

      }
      gpsLat = (gps.location.lat(), DEC);
      gpsLon = (gps.location.lng(), DEC);


      // turn off the gps
      digitalWrite(gpsCutoffPin, LOW);
    }

    void logInfo(){
      // Causes us to wait until we have satelite fix
      if(!gps.location.isValid())
      {
        Serial.println("Not a valid location. Waiting for satelite data.");

        //return;
      }
    else {
       //url += String(gps.location.lat(), DEC);

        //url += String(gps.location.lng(), DEC);
        Serial.println(gps.location.lat(), DEC);
        Serial.println(gps.location.lng(), DEC);
        stoploop = 2;
        //delay(1000);
    }
    previous = millis();
    }
```

I expect to see some gps data printed to the screen, but I actually don't see anything. I know that the gps is working and is receiving data because the blinking LED tell me so.

I have no idea how to fix this. If anyone could help I'd very much appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: An LED is not such a trustworthy guarantee that the GPS is sending data. Have you looked at the manual or documentation? If you need data infrequently, better connect and disconnect within the reading loop to make sure the GPS does not timeout and give up on sending.

Comment: Hi Marcos, I agree the LED isn't the best indication, but I run my script that I know is working before trying anything new (like the script above that doesn't work). I think my code is poorly optimised but I can't see how to make it more efficient.

Comment: My suggestion above, probably poorly phrased was to move the `gps_ss.begin(9600);` down to the beginning of your `GPS_mode()` function and close the connection after reading data with `gps_ss.end()`. That way you can make sure the GPS is not giving a timeout. Another thing I would suggest is to get rid of SoftwareSerial, but I guess you don't have more hardware ports.

Comment: Sadly that didn't work but thanks anyway. If I get rid of softwareserial I have no way to see what is going on.

Comment: I see... What I meant with get rid of SoftwareSerial was to replace it with a real hardware UART if you have one to spare. And if you don't you can just try to switch and use the GPS with the hardware Serial to see if things improve...